# Making Classes Exclusive to View Controllers - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

just a quick question to identify whether there is a bug in my code or I'm missing something more fundamental about the design of view-controllers in Xcode.

I'm building a gesture recognition app. This app requires multiple layers (view controllers) so that gestures can be applied to different contexts. E.G. in the "image" view controller, an outward pinch would zoom out. And in the "audio" view controller, an outward pinch would increase the volume. The problem that I'm having is that the "Custom Class" is ALWAYS executed once it has been enabled, even if the viewcontroller isn't enabled.

I used the storyboard editor to produce two different view controllers. On the initial controller everything works fine. Then after segue to the next view controller:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"imageSegue" sender: self];
```

The first class is STILL running in the background and causing the gestures to clash. Is there a way to make classes exclusive to certain view controllers?

I may be missing something fundamental here, but from the apple developer site, I can's see where I'm going wrong.

Thank you,
Tom.

Comment: So the app has a navigation controller whose root is CustomClass.  It performs a push segue to a different view controller, one with an imageView on it, and gestures don't work on that second one?  If so, post the gesture recognizer creation and it's action method from the second view controller.

Comment: Where/how are you adding the gesture recognizers? Are you adding them to the nav controller? To the window? To the current view?

Comment: I'm creating custom gesture recognisers, so it's all done programmatically. I haven't included a navigation controller. Could this be the problem? Thanks for your responses!